# Making fading effect with NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, nsview

I have a subview which I want to show up to make a dissolve fade effect. For that purpose, I'm trying to:

1. Show it
2. Fade it

For that purpose, I set a "showFade" method on my superview (Fader is the subview defined previously. someImage is already defined).

```
- (void)showFade {

  [Fader setHidden:NO];
  [Fader setImage: someImage];
  [[Fader animator] setHidden:YES];

}
```

The problem is: it works for the first time, and the subview fades, but it never shows up again. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** As requested, here is a more complete sample of the code

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

  Fader = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame: [self bounds]];
  Images[0] = @"Tower";
  Images[1] = @"Desert";
  Images[2] = @"Fall";
  image = 0;

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(showFader:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  [self addSubview: Fader];
  [self nextImage];
  [super awakeFromNib];

}

- (void)showFader: (NSTimer*)timer {

  [Fader setImage: [self image]];
  [Fader setHidden:NO];
  [[Fader animator] setHidden:YES];

  [self nextImage];

}

- (void)nextImage {
  if (image == 2) {
    image = 0;
  }
  else {
    image++;
  }

  [self setImage: [NSImage imageNamed: Images[image]]];

}
```

So, basically, I have a repeating timer making the parent NSImageView to loop between an array of images and making the "Fader" to show up with the previous image and fade out. The problem is that it only shows up once.

Comment: So where' s your code that *makes* it show up again?

Comment: Well, I tought that `[Fader setHidden:NO];` did it

Comment: No, what you did was tell it to show immediately, then asked its animator to hide it (with an animation). Nowhere do you ask it to show again (animated or not).

Comment: But that's the idea: to show it just for the animation to be able to fade it down again.

Comment: So subsequent calls to -showFade aren't working? How is this method called? Is "Fader" valid the second time this method is called? It should be clear by now that more information is required to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a long time ago (yet I never solved it), but I think this could have something to do with the fact that you ask your view to be showed **and** dissolved in the same event loop.

I guess you should let the event loop make an iteration (so that your view is actually displayed) before asking to dissolve the view.
I guess you could do it by setting a (short) timer that would fire a couple of millisecs after the view is displayed (by `setHidden:NO`).
I also guess there are easier ways to solve the problem (and I would be glad to hear them).

What is more, you could also try `animator setAlphaValue:0.0` to have a smooth transition.

I am not definitely not sure I have a correct answer, that's only a suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

hidden is a BOOL property, you can't animate BOOLs cause there are only two discrete values: NO and YES. Use the opacity instead, you can animate opacity from 1.0 (fully visible) to 0.0 (invisible) to fade out. And hidden has to be set to NO for this to work, otherwise it will be hidden all the time.

Comment: I think this doesn't matter if the view is layer backed. I think the hidden property uses the "default animation" for layer backed views (fade) in this case. I may be wrong.

Comment: yes you are wrong, this was specifically stated on WWDC 2010 session about core animation - you can't animate bool properties

Comment: Not directly, no (because you're right - there's nothing in between "true" and "false") but you can make it animatable *indirectly* by using a float "behind the scenes" when you build the animation for the bool property. Just like you can animate a "switch" flipping between on and off. Though it's "on" or "off", the position of the switch can be "tweened". So it's *possible*, I just don't know that -setHidden: has a default animation like removing/adding a subview.

Comment: Granted, the thing you'd "tween" for "hidden" would be its alpha value but the same can be said of the "add/remove subview" scenario. Adding/removing a view to/from a superview doesn't affect its alpha property (at least not the one we have access to, rather some "ultimate, final alpha value"), so -setHidden: doesn't have to either. Also consider it's "not possible" to animate a color change without rolling your own animatable property and handling the rgba (or whatever space) values yourself.

Comment: If it were possible to tween "hidden" property using opacitywas not a question: sure in theory it ks possible

Comment: If it were possible to tween "hidden" property using opacitywas not a question: sure in theory it is possible. Yet in the context of the question asked it is definitely not! Just two days ago I watched podcasts from WWDC 2010 flying over Atlantic, one about Core Animation, and trying to animate hidden property was an example of a typical pitfall and the solution named was to use opacity. So if I'm wrong (I didn't actually tried it for myself) then the Apple engineer at WWDC was also wrong :-)

Comment: And sorry for the broken comment: typing on an iphone is slow and stackoverflow didn't let me save an edit so i had to post it as a new comment

Answer (score -1):

This method works perfectly for me to make an image start out blurry and smoothly come into focus.

```
let parentView = UIView() 
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ImageToFocus"))
parentView.addSubview(imageView)
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurView.frame = imageView.frame
blurView.alpha = 1.0
self.blurTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: Selector("animateBlur:"), userInfo: blurView, repeats: true)

func animateBlur(timer:NSTimer)
{
    let blurView = timer.userInfo as UIVisualEffectView

    if blurView.alpha > 0.0 {
        blurView.alpha -= 0.05
    } else {
        blurTimer = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not about iOS or Swift.